# How to add Kalman filter to YOLO v2

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2017, kalman-filter, yolo

I would like to make people detection smooth by adding Kalman filter to YOLO.

In another post I noticed* (see code below in image.c file) how to get the coordinates of the bounding box in YOLO.

```
if(bot > im.h-1) bot = im.h-1;

// Print bounding box values 
printf("Bounding Box: Left=%d, Top=%d, Right=%d, Bottom=%d\n", left, top, right, bot); 
draw_box_width(im, left, top, right, bot, width, red, green, blue);
```

Comment: You're operating on a sequence of frames, with person detection in each, and trying to recover the speed with which each detection moves through the field of view?

Comment: Yes, I would like to achieve the same result as in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKXk6uB8348&feature=youtu.be).

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of using Kalman filter is for object tracking (not sure for smoothing). If C++ implementation is okay, You probably want to use this popular github repository https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

If you read the documentation, it has C++ API which you can use darknet as library (so you can use your yolo model) and load it to your C++ program. Take a look at C++ program example that use darknet library here https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/yolo_console_dll.cpp .

In that C++ code, the author gives 3 option to do object tracking, 1 of them is using kalman filter :

1. **Track Optical Flow** algorithm, but it only works for live detection, not for video. You can use the algorithm by uncomment this line `//#define TRACK_OPTFLOW` . Take a look at line 508 ~ 522

```
#ifdef TRACK_OPTFLOW
                        if (detection_data.new_detection) {
                            tracker_flow.update_tracking_flow(detection_data.cap_frame, detection_data.result_vec);
                            while (track_optflow_queue.size() > 0) {
                                draw_frame = track_optflow_queue.back();
                                result_vec = tracker_flow.tracking_flow(track_optflow_queue.front(), false);
                                track_optflow_queue.pop();
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            track_optflow_queue.push(cap_frame);
                            result_vec = tracker_flow.tracking_flow(cap_frame, false);
                        }
                        detection_data.new_detection = true;    // to correct kalman filter
#endif //TRACK_OPTFLOW
```

2. **Kalman Filter**, not really reccommended because it's not really accurate, but might work for CCTV or stationary camera. To use kalman filter change this value to true `bool const use_kalman_filter = false;`. Take a look at line 524 ~ 532

```
// track ID by using kalman filter
                        if (use_kalman_filter) {
                            if (detection_data.new_detection) {
                                result_vec = track_kalman.correct(result_vec);
                            }
                            else {
                                result_vec = track_kalman.predict();
                            }
                        }
```

3. **Custom Object Tracker**, I used this custom function and it performs better than kalman filter in my case, it will give you track ID for each object.

```
// track ID by using custom function
                        else {
                            int frame_story = std::max(5, current_fps_cap.load());
                            result_vec = detector.tracking_id(result_vec, true, frame_story, 40);
                        }
```